# Tight example for MST heuristic for metric TSP

Tags: algorithm

I'm looking for the tight example for MST heuristic which is and 2-approximation algorithm for metric Travelling Salesman Problem.

This algorithm can be found easily on the internet but I cannot find the tight example. By tight example I mean example in which given algorithm returns exactly 2 times worse solution than optimal.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest example that I can think of is like this.
Consider a star with n nodes: 1 node the center and n - 1 nodes surrounding it. every node is connected to center with cost 1.

Now put this star inside a cycle of length (n - 1) where each two nodes are connected by cost 2. Note that the nodes of cycle are the non-center nodes. Now, MST will give cost n - 1.
And TSP approx. using MST will give (n - 2)*2 + 1

So, the ratio of approx is (2n - 3) / (n - 1) which tends to 2 (what you want) as n grows large.